# IntelliJ IDEA on Mac. Is it possible to build my Kotlin Native project from the commandline without the IDE?

Tags: macos, kotlin, intellij-idea, command-line, build

Quite new to all things Kotlin / IntelliJ / IDEA / gradle.

I'm comparing some code in about ten languages and the Kotlin Native version is the only one that I can't figure out how to build without using the IDE.

I started the project in IntelliJ IDEA by following guides on getting started with Kotlin and this was the recommended method.

By Googling, searching the IntelliJ help, and hunting here on StackOverflow I've been unable to find the answer. Most questions are about Multiplatform and phone apps. I'm just making a macOS commandline tool for now.

Is there a way included with IntelliJ IDEA to build a project form the terminal without starting up the IDE?

Or would it actually require me to use a completely different build system and just use Kotlin Native Mono install totally separate from the IntelliJ setup? Is no shared build system possible or would that be an even more advanced proposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use the IntelliJ IDEA to build the Kotlin native project.
You should be able to use the `gradle build` or `gradle nativeBinaries` command from the Terminal to build the Gradle project.

Also, you could refer to the Kotlin native documentation here for details: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-gradle.html

Comment: So when you say there's no need does that mean it's optional and I can use both and by installing IntelliJ IDEA I can already also use `gradle` or do you actually mean I have to set up the program again a different way and then won't be able to use it with IDEA any more? The link seems to involve starting again from scratch, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @hippietrail The same project works for the IDEA and command line. In the IDEA case, it will download a Gradle and run it under the hood. In the command case, you could install the Gradle via brew or something else and run it. You could also run `gradle wrapper` which could create the gradlew file in your project root and you could use the `./gradlew any_gradle_command_here` in another computer without installing the Gradle manually (it will download the Gradle for you) See here for details: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: In general, the IDEA project wizard should include the `gradlew` in this project root so others could run `./gradlew build` to build it but it seems it doesn't include it in the Kotlin native project. I have created an issue for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-24569/No-gradlew-and-gradlew.bat-files-generated-when-creating-MPP-projects

Comment: Ah thanks. I thought I was lost when I had no `gradle` in my path. I do have a `gradle` directory in the project dir and a `gradlew` shell script. And I see `gradlew build` works and is of course simpler than my hacky answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a bit more trial and error.

IntelliJ IDEA seems to come with `gradle` but doesn't put it in the path. The IntelliJ IDEA project has set up a build system that will work with gradle as is though. You don't have to set up a new one from scratch.

In my case the gradle executable was at:

`~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.4.2-bin/48ivgl02cpt2ed3fh9dbalvx8/gradle-7.4.2/bin/gradle`

Running gradle using the full path with no parameters looks like it's doing something and takes a while, but doesn't build the project. To build it simply add the `build` parameter so in my case:

`~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.4.2-bin/48ivgl02cpt2ed3fh9dbalvx8/gradle-7.4.2/bin/gradle build`

---

It seems that `gradle` is not in the path by design and that the intended usage is via the `gradlew` that IntelliJ IDEA put in my project directory for me. This is an (explicit) wrapper script for gradle. So the more straightforward invocation is:

`./gradlew build`